# How to implement offset into jquery waypoint code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I am very new to jQuery and don't quite understand it yet so I could be not understanding something very simple. So I've created a sticky nav for anchor links that highlight as the user scrolls down the page. In order to create this I used the jquery waypoint.js and I currently have this working. The issue I am having is I need the highlight to trigger 50px above it's current location, so in the waypoint.js there is an offset option but I can't get the code to work. How do I implement the offset from waypoint.js?

Thanks for the help!

//here is the offset code from waypoint that I need to implement into the code below— How do I use this in my code below?

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('number-offset'),
  handler: function(direction) {
  notify('25px from top')
  },
   offset: 25
})
```

// here is the code that is creating the highlights on the nav elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var waypoint0 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('work'),
        handler: function() {

            $('a[href="#work"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })
    var waypoint1 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('about'),
        handler: function() {
            $('a[href="#work"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
            $('a[href="#about"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })
    var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('contact'),
        handler: function() {
            $('a[href="#about"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
            $('a[href="#contact"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })   


  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you would just need to add the "offset" property to those existing waypoint declarations.

Current:

```
  var waypoint0 = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('work'),
    handler: function() {

        $('a[href="#work"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
    }
  });
```

New:

```
  var waypoint0 = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('work'),
    handler: function() {

        $('a[href="#work"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
    },
    offset: 50
  });
```

Source: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/